# horizontalalingment in textblock don't work

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have code like this in xaml:

```
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Referee}" Width="120" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="LOL" Margin="0 0 5 0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
```

The problem is fact that first textBlock is not aligned to right but still to left.

There are many listbox items and i want to have align first column to right and second column to left. In each stackPanel first textblock has width 120. ListBox is in grid column which column width is set to Auto.

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the TextAlignment property

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Referee}" Width="120" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 5 0" TextAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

A stack panel by default stacks items from left to right (this can be changed by setting FlowDirection="RightToLeft") therefor it doesn't matter if the stack panel spans the entire area available, the first item will always dock to the left no matter how you align it.

```
<ListBoxItem>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Referee}" Width="120" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 5 0"></TextBlock>
          <TextBlock Text="LOL" Margin="0 0 5 0"></TextBlock>
     </StackPanel>
</ListBoxItem>
```

However if you want one text block to be docked to the left and the other to the right, then you should either use a DockPanel or a Grid.

With a DockPanel:

```
<ListBoxItem>
     <DockPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Referee}" Width="120" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 5 0" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></TextBlock>
          <TextBlock Text="LOL" Margin="0 0 5 0" DockPanel.Dock="Left"></TextBlock>
     </DockPanel>
</ListBoxItem>
```

With a Grid:

```
<ListBoxItem>
     <Grid>
          <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Referee}" Width="120" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
          <TextBlock Text="LOL" Margin="0 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
     </Grid>
</ListBoxItem>
```

Both a grid and a dock panel will fill the space given to them by their parent by default. And the last child of the dock panel will fill the remaining available space if no width/height is specified.

Answer (score -1):

Set the StackPanel's property "HorizontalAlignment" to "Stretch".